# How would I bulk load the data into a SQL Server table which is referenced by the foreign keys but the data is plain in Excel format?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have a table `BasicDetails` with these columns:

```
ID   Name   Father    Country_ID   City_ID   ContactDetails_ID
```

But client has shared Excel sheets with me and I should be loading that into the table. The sheet has the following columns

```
ID   Name   Father   CountryName   CountryCode   CityName   CityCode   ContactNo   CellNo   Address
```

Now, in my database `CountryName, CountryCode, CityName` these are stored in a separate table named `Countries`.

`CityName  CityCode` are saved in a separate table `Cities`.

`ContactNo   CellNo   Address` are stored in a separate table `ContactDetails`

Their respective primary keys are used as foreign key in the main table.

Now the problem is that I the sheets has thousands of records and I cannot figure out how do i import the data into the `BasicDetails` table which is referenced by foreign keys.

Comment: Create a Dump table. Populate that from excel using whatever ETL process suits you. Then create a stored procedure that merges the Dump table appropriately. I assume you have some programming experience with TSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this in multiple parts.

Load the Excel tables into a staging table, say `staging`.

Then, be sure that the foreign key references work, for instance:

```
select s.countrycode, count(*)
from staging s left join
     countries c
     on s.countrycode = c.countrycode
where c.countrycode is null
group by s.countrycode;
```

You need to repeat this for `cities` and `contacts`.  The latter may be more complicated.  This question does not ask what to do about conflicting information -- if you need help with that, ask a NEW question.

When you are satisfied that all the reference tables are correct, you can load the table using `join`s:

```
insert into basicdata (Name, Father, Country_ID, City_ID ContactDetails_ID)
    select s.name, s.father, co.country_id, ci.city_id,
           con.contact_id
    from staging s join
         counties co
         on s.countrycode = co.countrycode join
         cities ci
         on s.citycode = ci.citycode join
         contacts con
         on s.contacctno = con.contactno;
```